# Chrome how to disable cache

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Since I got a new pc, I can no longer debug directly from IE, unless start the debugging session and throw in the URL, which is not efficient.  I am having to use Chrome, and even with F12 debugging tools Network Disable cache, I need to clear my cache after I make JavaScript changes.

Re-naming my scripts each time would not be efficient.

Can you please tell me how to disable the cache as before I got my new pc?

Thanks,
Kenny

Comment: Best way you can run your project - then Crtl + f5

Comment: Comment seems to work

Comment: Yes should be work.